# How Can I achieve Multiple Layout in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I  have requirement of multiple layout in my react application. I want two different layout one for login and sign up and one for my dashboard /home how can i achieve it , i want it done in react-router v4

Comment: Just write different components with different styling for every screen and hook it to react router. I don't see a problem here.